# Braintree get token of payment method in frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, braintree

I have an app, where the payment methods are stored in the vault, but for simplicity's sake, only one should be allowed to be stored.

Right now I delete all the payment methods, before starting the flow for a new one because I can't get a hold of the payment method token on the client side (and I don't see any other way to delete a payment method).

Optimally, I would like to delete the method directly in the frontend. If that is not possible, I would like to get the token, so that I can selectively delete in the backend.

Is there any way to do what I want to do?